# Url amigable con 3 parámetros con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Que tal estoy intentando pasar esta url, la cual tiene 3 parámetros pk,torneo y liga es la siguiente:

> http://localhost/web/play/pk=566539&torneo=mlb&liga=NN

y lo que quiero es lograr que se vea de la siguiente manera:

> http://localhost/web/play/566539/mlb/NN

En mi archivo **.htaccess** tengo la siguiente configuracion:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on


#RewriteRule ^play/([0-9]+)$  play.php?pk=$1

RewriteRule ^play([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ play.php?pk=$1&torneo=$2&liga=$3 [L]



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo tengo un htaccess así

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Creo que es suficiente para lo que quieres hacer.
Lo siguiente es cambiar la forma en manejas los parámetros por URL
En lugar de enviar el identificador de variable y su valor, solo envía los valores en orden. Puedes obtener los valores haciendo un explode a la URL.

```
$url = explode("/", $_GET["url"]);
```

Ahora sabes que cada posición del arreglo $url es un valor de los parámetros enviados, por ejemplo:

```
$url[0] será igual a "566539"
$url[1] será igual a "mlb"
$url[2] será igual a "NN"
```

Si lo que quieres es cambiar la apariencia del URL, basta con acceder a la dirección de la forma en que quieres que se vea. Si usas el htaccess que te proporcioné ahí, podrás obtener los valores como te mostré.
No dudes en preguntar.

Comment: la variable $url de donde la saco ?

Comment: Listo, lo solucione de la siguiente forma: RewriteRule ^play/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ play.php?pk=$1&torneo=$2&liga=$3 [L,QSA]